# Find the number of time a row from one dataframe appears in another dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data.frame with 90k rows named "sourceToDestination".

[image]

Many of these rows in the data.frame above are duplicated. Using the unique command I created another data.frame which lists only the unique rows from the above data.frame and named it "sourceToDestinationUnique".

[image]

Now in this data.frame which shows unique values, I want to add another column at the very end which lists count. And the count column specified how many times each of these unique rows appear in the original data.frame.

I tried using the command below to check how many times row 1 in unique data.frame is present in original data.frame:

```
> sourceToDestinationUnique[1,] %in% sourceToDestination
```

But it gives me this strange answer:

```
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Kindly let me know which command to use? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest another way that can archive your purpose:

```
 sourceToDestinationUnique <- aggregate(list(dupCount=rep(1,nrow(sourceToDestination))), sourceToDestination, length)
```

Let's print out the df sourceToDestinationUnique to see the result.

Comment: Thanks a lot. By the way suppose i want to know the index numbers of all those rows in `dupCount` column i.e. if say a row has a value of 5 in `dupCount` that means it occurs 5 times. How do i know those 5 indexes so I can look them up?

Comment: aggregate(x=list(dupIndices=(1:nrow(sourceToDestination))), sourceToDestination, cbind)

Comment: or: aggregate(x=list(dupIndices=(1:nrow(sourceToDestination))), sourceToDestination, FUN=function(x) c(cbind(x), length(x)))